# Retrieve a list of States/Provinces for a Country with a REST/Javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm searching for an API that allows me to retrieve a list of states/provinces of the country that I search for. I repeat the countryName or ISO, **not** a Latlng / geocoding.

The closest thing I came across was this: 
https://code.google.com/p/risevision/wiki/States_v2

However that is for US and Canada only.

A database with countries and states/provinces to pull from is my second choice.

Does anyone have another idea?

Comment: I'd take the list of states from [ISO 3166-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2) and create my own table for it.

Comment: @Jordão which is my second choice. But I prefer an API

Answer (score 1):

The Natural Earth Data in Fusion Tables has that data in it.

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=19lLpgsKdJRHL2O4fNmJ406ri9JtpIIk8a-AchA

[example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test//v3_FusionTables_CountryBrowser_encryptedID.html)

Comment: +1 Gosh you're such a wonderful person I have seen.  I love all your examples especially this is my favorite from today.

Answer (score -2):

You can make use of [Geoname's Webservices](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html),

It Provides Rest APIs but you need a registration

**Updates:**

Try the below API

http://api.geonames.org/countryInfo?country=US&username=demo

response:

```
<geonames>
<country>
<countryCode>US</countryCode>
<countryName>United States</countryName>
<isoNumeric>840</isoNumeric>
<isoAlpha3>USA</isoAlpha3>
<fipsCode>US</fipsCode>
<continent>NA</continent>
<continentName>North America</continentName>
<capital>Washington</capital>
<areaInSqKm>9629091.0</areaInSqKm>
<population>310232863</population>
<currencyCode>USD</currencyCode>
<languages>en-US,es-US,haw,fr</languages>
<geonameId>6252001</geonameId>
<west>-124.733253</west>
<north>49.388611</north>
<east>-66.954811</east>
<south>24.544245</south>
</country>
</geonames>
```

Comment: I only see Country Subdivision / reverse geocoding, no way to recieve provinces/states based on a country name.

Comment: @Sem Actually you misunderstood.  check this API http://api.geonames.org/countryInfo?country=US&username=demo  Go through the docs

Comment: I don't see a list of States/provinces just basic information of the country. I would need something like http://api.geonames.org/countrySubdivision?country=US&username=demo

Comment: You can do it with: http://api.geonames.org/search?country=US&fcode=ADM1&username=demo
The only thing it is missing is the 2 letter abbreviation, which I haven't been able to figure out yet.

Comment: Ok, figured out how to get abbreviations, add the style=FULL
ex. http://api.geonames.org/search?country=CA&fcode=ADM1&style=FULL&username=demo

You will now get the list of alternateName.  The one <alternateName lang="abbr"> is the abbreviation.